# wxpython determine whether a mouse or a key triggered the set focus event

Tags: wxpython

is it possible in wxpython to determine how a widget recieved its focus?
ie by mouse click or the tab key or an arrow key etc
thanks :)

Comment: out of curiosity, why does it matter?

Comment: im making my own textctrl from scratch for looks etc. ok so now if the user clicks on it i need to set the blinker position at that point, if its focus has been set by tab or an arrow key the blinker position can just stay at the end

Comment: suppose i could just bind to the left down event. i thought a function that determines the way focus is set would be usefull tho :)

Answer (score 0):

I played around this and found that the EVT_SET_FOCUS only carries information about the window which was left. So you really want to bind the EVT_LEFT_DOWN.

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.last_was_mouse = False

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Test")
        self.button2 = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Test")
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer.Add(self.button)
        self.sizer.Add(self.button2)
        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)
        self.Show()

        self.button2.Bind(wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.OnFocus)
        self.button2.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnMouse)


    def OnFocus(self, e):
        if self.last_was_mouse:
            print "Focus by mouse"
        else:
            print "Focus by keyboard"
        self.last_was_mouse = False

    def OnMouse(self, e):
        self.last_was_mouse = True
        e.Skip()

app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```